# Encrypt-then-MAC, how to afterwards add data to HMAC

Tags: c#, .net, hmac

I want to **include** `iv` and `salt` in the HMACSHA512 calculation **without** add then to the encrypted data.
 At the moment someone could change the `iv` and a wouldn't noticed that.

I chain different streams to ensure Encrypt-then-MAC, later I want to encrypt large files, so this design is necessary.
So if I add the the `iv` and `salt` to a stream, with e.g. `new MemoryStream(iv).CopyTo(hmacStream);` the result will contain this data.

This is my code so far:

```
    private static IHmacAndData EncryptInternal(byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] plainData, byte[] salt)
    {
        byte[] hmacHash;
        byte[] encryptedBytes;

        using (var aesManaged = CreateAesManaged(iv, key))
        {
            var encryptor = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor(aesManaged.Key, aesManaged.IV);
            var hmacsha512 = new HMACSHA512(key);

            using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var hmacStream = new CryptoStream(resultStream, hmacsha512, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var aesStream = new CryptoStream(hmacStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (var plainStream = new MemoryStream(plainData))
                        {
                            plainStream.CopyTo(aesStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                encryptedBytes = resultStream.ToArray();
            }
            hmacHash = hmacsha512.Hash;
        }

        return new Message {HMAC = hmacHash, Data = encryptedBytes};
    }

    private static AesManaged CreateAesManaged(byte[] iv, byte[] key)
    {
        var aesManaged = new AesManaged
        {
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            KeySize = KeySize,
            IV = iv,
            Key = key
        };
        return aesManaged;
    }
```

My temporary solution is to make a **second HMACSHA512 calculation** at the end.
But this seems not right in any way.

```
var overallHmac = new HMACSHA512(keyHmac);
hmacHash = overallHmac.ComputeHash(hmacHash.Concat(iv).Concat(saltPassword).Concat(saltHmac).ToArray());
```

Here is the full sample, search for `CreateOverallHmacKey` to find the spot.
https://gist.github.com/dhcgn/85b88b516953e8996af8544ee9d7b567

Comment: See [RNCryptor-Spec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md) for an example of how to secure symmetries encryption.

Comment: @zaph interesting link, thx. but it doesn't help me with my concrete implementation.

Comment: I usually include extra data in the buffer that created the hmac value.  The extra values do not actually get transmitted in the payload. (iv and salt in your case are the extra data).  The recv end knows to put back the extra data in the right spot to then recreate or verify the HMAC.  If the rcv end does not have the iv and salt then the hamc fails and I know the senders and receivers configs or payload are untrustworthy, but I do not care which one is wrong at runtime – I just know they are both not right and so the payload goes outside of the happy path.

Comment: @hdev I know it's been quite some time now, but have you found a solution to that?

Comment: Just use `System.Security.Cryptography.AesGcm` this is an authenticated encryption algorithm. no need of HMAC.