# HMACSHA512 different hashes when reuse instance with CryptoStream

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, hmac

I have a use case, where I want to create a second HMAC where the first HMAC and some data is combined.

**I would like to understand why the test case 3 is creating a *wrong* hmac,** this is confusing because 1 und 2 are creating the same hash.

Code:

```
void Main()
{
    { // 0. Create a HMAC 
        byte[] keyHmac = new byte[] { 255 };
        var hmac = new HMACSHA512(keyHmac); // 1st HMACSHA512 ctor
        var result = hmac.ComputeHash(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        Console.Out.WriteLine($"0. - {Convert.ToBase64String(result)}");
    }

    Console.Out.WriteLine("\r\nThe following MACs should be all equal!\r\n");

    { // 1. Create a HMAC than add a byte to the result and create a second HMAC
        byte[] keyHmac = new byte[] { 255 };
        var hmac = new HMACSHA512(keyHmac); // 1st HMACSHA512 ctor
        var result = hmac.ComputeHash(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        result = hmac.ComputeHash(result.Concat(new byte[] { 7 }).ToArray());
        Console.Out.WriteLine($"1. - {Convert.ToBase64String(result)}");
    }

    { // 2. Create a HMAC than add a byte to the result and create a second HMAC with a new instance
        byte[] keyHmac = new byte[] { 255 };
        var hmac = new HMACSHA512(keyHmac);  // 1st HMACSHA512 ctor
        var result = hmac.ComputeHash(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        hmac = new HMACSHA512(keyHmac);  // 2nd HMACSHA512 ctor
        result = hmac.ComputeHash(result.Concat(new byte[] { 7 }).ToArray());
        Console.Out.WriteLine($"2. - {Convert.ToBase64String(result)}");
    }

    { // 3. Create a HMAC from a stream than add a byte to the result and create a second HMAC
        byte[] keyHmac = new byte[] { 255 };
        var hmac = new HMACSHA512(keyHmac);
        using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var hmacStream = new CryptoStream(resultStream, hmac, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }).CopyTo(hmacStream);
            }
        }

        var result = hmac.Hash;
        result = hmac.ComputeHash(result.Concat(new byte[] { 7 }).ToArray());

        Console.Out.WriteLine($"3. - {Convert.ToBase64String(result)}");
    }


    { // 4. Create a HMAC from a stream than add a byte to the result and create a second HMAC with a new instance
        byte[] keyHmac = new byte[] { 255 };
        var hmac = new HMACSHA512(keyHmac);
        using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var hmacStream = new CryptoStream(resultStream, hmac, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }).CopyTo(hmacStream);
            }
        }

        var result = hmac.Hash;
        hmac = new HMACSHA512(keyHmac);
        result = hmac.ComputeHash(result.Concat(new byte[] { 7 }).ToArray());

        Console.Out.WriteLine($"4. - {Convert.ToBase64String(result)}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0. - J0x6KRHzGh1nTLL+a+pL8H9PJyl1b9/rL7D0j3S1DBpMduct37uMi0mBFEOdkfrLs2Ipn39yoV6GaRoEK+hU7A==

The following MACs should be all equal!

1. - mVd7YQ7AbmRfH57AprAuU1vlSuOucvg+NbUFl7eNurPuvGS/Xrko2Kz3d9vUGXr0P287dOgEKQJDNfMkN2xi5Q==
2. - mVd7YQ7AbmRfH57AprAuU1vlSuOucvg+NbUFl7eNurPuvGS/Xrko2Kz3d9vUGXr0P287dOgEKQJDNfMkN2xi5Q==
3. - DVncxk/dEYhmmpK5qEnVg0Pc0/MUe8APbAiyZrh+ba35oGv2TGCkFco3gFVZ2gl+h3DpcqP7VbmuthBmCvSKlg==
4. - mVd7YQ7AbmRfH57AprAuU1vlSuOucvg+NbUFl7eNurPuvGS/Xrko2Kz3d9vUGXr0P287dOgEKQJDNfMkN2xi5Q==
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 3rd case you mixed calls to `TransformBlock`/`TransformFinalBlock` (used by `CryptoStream`) with calls to `ComputeHash`. The two approaches each seem interfere with an assumption about the state machine that the other has.

It's fine to use one approach, or the other, but mixing them doesn't go so hot.

If instead of using CryptoStream you used `HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Stream)` your 3rd case should work.

Comment: This is a linked question regarding CryptoStream http://stackoverflow.com/q/39637026/1776231

Comment: Shouldn't the state machine throw an exception if I get in an invalid state?

Comment: Well, the biggest problem is that TransformFinalBlock doesn't call Initialize(), so the hash doesn't reset to the no-data state. The other direction has similar problems, TransformBlock before ComputeHash counts as pretending the data in TransformBlock.  And while you see this is a bug for your application, an app depending on these behaviors sees "fixing" it as a bug to theirs. (You could reset your state by calling ComputeHash(Array.Empty<byte>))

Comment: Could I block the call of TransformFinalBlock and add some data later?

Answer (score 1):

That's because in all methods except 3 you reinitialize your hmac between first hash computation and second one. To do the same in 3, try this:

```
{
    // 3. Create a HMAC from a stream than add a byte to the result and create a second HMAC
    byte[] keyHmac = new byte[] {255};
    var hmac = new HMACSHA512(keyHmac);
    using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream()) {
       using (var hmacStream = new CryptoStream(resultStream, hmac, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
           new MemoryStream(new byte[] {1, 2, 3}).CopyTo(hmacStream);
        }
    }

    var result = hmac.Hash;
    hmac = new HMACSHA512(keyHmac);
    result = hmac.ComputeHash(result.Concat(new byte[] {7}).ToArray());

    Console.Out.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToBase64String(result)}");
}
```

Comment: In (1) I call  the ctor HMACSHA512 only once, so I didn't reinitialize the hmac there. Or do I miss something?